# Conditional expectation, cartesian product

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $\Omega=X\times Y$ be a sample space of pairs $(x,y)$.

Let $\zeta$ be a random variable on $\Omega$.

How would you interpret notation $\mathbb{E}(\zeta \mid x)$? Does this have any sense? I've never come across this. Any ideas?

Comment: For each $x$ in $X$, $E(\zeta\mid x)$ is a (bad) notation for the quantity $A(x)$ where $A$ the function $A$ is defined, up to a null event, by $A(\xi)=E(\zeta\mid\xi)$ and $\xi:X\times Y\to X$ is defined by $\xi(x,y)=x$ for every $(x,y)$ in $X\times Y$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I think they mean. The random variable $\zeta$ is a function $X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Given that we choose a certain $x\in X$ we have the function $\zeta|_{x\times Y}:x\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I guess they mean the expectation of this random variable (You might need to rescale to actually make it a random variable).

Comment: ot expectation is basically some new random variable on $X$ right?

Comment: The new random variable is basically a random varaible on $Y$, since we fix one point in $X$.

Comment: i mean expectation of that new random variable is dependent on x right?

Comment: Yes exactly, because of the values of $\zeta|_{x\times Y}$ depend on $x$.